# XmlDocument.Load xml file failed

Tags: c#, xmldocument

Just try to load an xml file in C#, but keep getting an exception.

Here are the code:

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load(@"C:\test.XML");
```

Here is the error message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in System.Xml.dll
>   Additional information: Could not find file 'C:\ndentity.ent'.

I tried to move the xml file around on my local machine, but keep getting the error like "Could not find file '...\ndentity.ent'. Am I missing anything?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is `C:\ndentity.ent`?

Comment: try with xDoc.Load(@"C:\\test.XML");

Comment: @Rana there's no need for \\ that's what @ is for

Comment: @Amit Kumar Ghosh - i don't know and it also confuses me. it is a part of the error message.  no matter where i put the "test.xml", i will get it at the end of the error message.

Comment: @WillYin Is that file name referenced anywhere within your xml?

Comment: @Rana, I tried, it did not work.

Comment: @juharr - the file name is not referenced anywhere within the xml. i just tried to rename the file, but still got the same error.

Comment: Is this the actually code or just an example?  Specifically does the actual code pass a string literal to `Load` or a variable?  If that latter when you debug what is the value of that variable.  If the former then this is beyond odd.

Comment: @juharr, please see my post below.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
  doc.LoadXml(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\test.XML"));
```

Comment: Why would this work when `xDoc.Load(path);` doesn't?  The overload that takes the path should be internally doing almost the exact same [thing](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/Xml/System/Xml/Dom/XmlDocument@cs/1305376/XmlDocument@cs).

Comment: Thanks for that, I was under the impression that XmlDocument does not take a file name in the load method.

Comment: All, thank you for the reply. reminded by juharr, i figure out the problem, which is in xml file. the xml file is from a customer, which has this line <!DOCTYPE ndxml PUBLIC "-//...//ENTITIES/Latin" "ndentity.ent"> . if i delete this line, the file will be loaded. is it possible load the file with this line?